# Sybase Central - Why is this VARCHAR field being converted to a NUMERIC?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase, sqlanywhere

In my DEV environment I am using `Sybase Central` 16.0.0 build 2043 whereas in my UAT environment I am using 16.0.0 build 1948.  I have a `BEGIN END` statement that uses a cursor to iterate over the records of a small table.  One of the things the cursor does is concatenate all the columns of the current row into a single `LONG VARCHAR` variable.  In DEV the code works fine

```
BEGIN 
    DECLARE concatenateTest LONG VARCHAR;

    DECLARE cursTEST CURSOR FOR
    SELECT A_NUMERIC_FIELD || '' || A_VARCHAR_FIELD AS ROW_DETAIL
    FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE;

    OPEN cursTEST;
    FETCH NEXT cursTEST INTO concatenateTest;

    WHILE @@sqlstatus = 0 LOOP
        MESSAGE 'ROW_DETAIL: ', concatenateTest TYPE STATUS TO CLIENT;
        FETCH NEXT cursTEST INTO concatenateTest;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cursTEST;
END;
```

In UAT (the older build) the script encounters an error because for some reason it tries to convert the contents of the `A_VARCHAR_FIELD` to a `NUMERIC` value.  I can get around the problem by casting but why is the behaviour different between the two Sybase Central versions?

Comment: Why are you even using a cursor (which will be slow) when you could just create the concenated string in a select statement to begin with?

Comment: I have a business requirement to iterate through the table and perform an operation every N rows.  I'll also need to concatenate the values of every row into a variable that is incremented with each row's data as I go through the data.  I'm using a cursor because I thought that was the fastest way of iterating through a large dataset as well as giving me "control" over what I do with the data.

Comment: Its still usually much faster to fill a temp table with the primary keys, then process the N 'top' rows from the temp table on the key value then remove the same keys in a while loop. This gives you cursor-styleprocessing but without the locking and performance issues they bring.

Comment: I'd tried using that approach but tested it on a table with about ~500,000 records and it proved much slower.  This is the code I was using:

Comment: BEGIN
        DECLARE uid BIGINT;

        SELECT MY_ID INTO #temp FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY MY_ID ASC;

        WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #temp) LOOP    
            SET rowcount 1;
            SELECT MY_ID INTO uid FROM #temp;
            SET rowcount 0;
            DELETE FROM #temp WHERE MY_ID = uid;
            MESSAGE 'MY ID is currently: ', uid type status to client;
        END LOOP;

    END;

Comment: You're doing it one row at a time rather than N rows at a time there :)

Comment: I (or rather someone on my team) found a solution to the problem of using a cursor.  I posted the response here, if it's of interest :-) @RichCampbell

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215723/sybase-stored-procedure-called-from-within-another-stored-procedure-is-too-slow/54461572#54461572] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215723/sybase-stored-procedure-called-from-within-another-stored-procedure-is-too-slow/54461572#54461572)